# Watir-webdriver rails integration with minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, watir-webdriver, minitest

Looking for equivalent of the gem minitest-rails-capybara for watir-webdriver, or in other words having the tests automatically start and stop the rails server.

This is for the purposes of a continuous integration server, where I don't want to muck about with manually starting and stopping the rails server for only minitest:integration.

Answer (score 2):

There is watir-rails project and Ruby gem: https://github.com/watir/watir-rails

Comment: Thanks, this should be what I am looking for. Now I just need to figure out how to configure it.

Comment: There's not much to configure :) Just start using it.